# How to import the correct Hibernate version for a JBoss 7 project?

Tags: hibernate, maven-3, jboss7.x

I must create an `org.hibernate.Interceptor` in my `war` project which will be deployed to JBoss 7.

That concept (Interceptors) doesn't exist in JPA so I must use the dependency of hibernate to do that.

I know that to use the JPA dependency of JBoss 7 in my project I can write that in my `pom.xml` :

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
```

But how can I import the version of hibernate used in JBoss 7 ? It seems that the `org.jboss.jbossas.jboss-as-component-matrix` that existed with previous versions doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: Perhaps http://relation.to/Bloggers/SomeTipsOnUsingHibernateInJBossAS700Final gives some info?

Comment: No, sorry @Raghuram, the link you give doesn't say how to declare the hibernate version of JBoss 7 in the pom.xml of my project. What I did at the moment is looking in the jar given with JBoss 7 to get the correct hibernate version, and make en dependency to that specific version in my pom.xml.